# When is the Receipt's identifier generated?

Tags: transactions, receipts

Like stated within the question.

When does Ethereum generate an identifier of a receipt which can be used to retrieve the transaction result. Is it generated instantly upon reception of the transaction by a full-node?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is returned right after the transaction is sent and a transaction hash is available.

Read the first bullet on the return value of function `web3.eth.sendTransaction` [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#eth-sendtransaction-return).